# Form a string using characters provided taken from various input strings. Check for error, it throws NZEC error on submitting

Tags: java, algorithm

In this question we need to find the number of "codechef" that we can form using the characters taken from input strings.

> First line is number of test cases and next line is the number of
>   input string. The output is a single integer value representing the
>   number of "codechef" string that can be formed from the given
>   characters.

It **throws NZEC error** on submitting and when I use `try catch` block to avoid it, it **shows wrong answer**. This is a question from codechef beginners section.
[Problem Link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CFMM)
My approach:

1. Store every character from the input `string` into a `Hashmap` with the frequency.
2. Create one character array containing the characters used in the word `"codechef"`. And another integer array contains the frequency of these corresponding characters, here my arrays are

   char[ ] c ={c,o,d,e,h,f}

   int[ ] arr={2,1,1,2,1,1}
3. I run a loop traversing each character in hashmap and delete the character count needed for a word formation. Every complete traversal will give one increment in count.

Implementation:

```
import java.util.*;

import java.lang.*;

import java.io.*;



class Codechef
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception

{

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int T = sc.nextInt();

        while(T-->0){

            int n = sc.nextInt();

            sc.nextLine();

            String s;

            HashMap<Character,Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

            for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){

                s = sc.nextLine();

                for(int j = 0;j < s.length();j++){

                    if(hmap.containsKey(s.charAt(j)))

                        hmap.put(s.charAt(j),hmap.get(s.charAt(j))+1);

                    else

                        hmap.put(s.charAt(j),1);
                }
            }

            /*  for(Map.Entry entry:hmap.entrySet()){

                    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+": "+entry.getValue());

                }*/

            int arr[] = {2,1,1,2,1,1};

            char crr[] = {'c','o','d','e','h','f'};

            int count = 0;

            int i = 0;

            boolean flag = true;

            while(flag){

                if(hmap.get(crr[i])>=arr[i])
                    hmap.put(crr[i],hmap.get(crr[i])-arr[i]);

                 else flag = false;

                 if(i==5 && flag)
                 {
                     count++;

                     i = 0;

                 }

                 else

                 i++;

            }

           System.out.println(count);

        }

    sc.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: So what is your question

Comment: The code throws NZEC error on submitting in codechef. And when I use try catch block it shows wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(hmap.get(crr[i])>=arr[i])`

This line contains an Exception what if hmap does not contain crr[i].
 
Try catch will always give wrong answer in these sites because these sites only checks what answer your code is producing.